# Format entity-elations as dictionary thru regex

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary

I have a string of the form --

`test = "<bos> <rel> headquarters location <ent> American Airlines <ent> Texas <rel> headquarters location <ent> Southwest Airlines <ent> Texas <rel> ops base <ent> United <ent> Chicago <eos>"`

where I want to format relations in the form of a dictionary of `<str: relation type>::<set: pairs of entities>` form --

```
{ "headquarters location" : [set(American Airlines, Texas), set(Southwest Airlines, Texas)], "ops base" : [set(United, Chicago)] }
```

The way I am trying to do this --

```
rel_set = {}
for m in re.findall(r'(<\w+>)\s+([^<]+)', test):
    if m[0] == '<rel>':
        l = rel_set.setdefault(m[1].strip(), [])
    elif m[0] == '<ent>':
        l.append(m[1].strip())
rel_set = dict(zip(rel_set.keys(), map(set, rel_set.values())))
```

And I end up with --

```
{'headquarters location': set('American Airlines', 'Southwest Airlines', 'Texas'), 'ops base': set('Chicago', 'United')}
```

i.e. for `hq location`, the loop I have simply amends an existing set for the given key, whereas I want it to create an additional set.

I am looking for an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach may not be the best, but I've worked with it and rewritten your code a bit. If you find any flaws in theory or practice, please report it.

The idea is to initialize **s** as an empty set and add elements to it that come after the **ent** tag. If there is a tag other than **ent** and **s** is not empty, add **s** to **l** and reassign **s** to an empty set.

`if m[0] != '<ent>':` is necessary because a sequence of **ent** tags can terminate not only with **rel** tag, but also with **eos** tag, for example.

The `if s:` is needed to check whether **l** has already been initialized, so an exception will not be thrown due to a non-existent **l**.

(Note: in cases such as `<rel> text <ent> <ent> <rel>`, **s** becomes `{''}` and evaluates as `True`)

At least one flaw i see at the moment is cases where **ent** precedes **rel**. I think that it can be handled.

```
import re
rel_set = {}
s=set()
for m in re.findall(r'(<\w+>)\s*([^<]*)', test):
    if m[0] != '<ent>':
        if s:
            l.append(s)
            s=set()
        if m[0] == '<rel>':
            go=True            
            l = rel_set.setdefault(m[1].strip(), [])
    elif m[0] == '<ent>':
        s.add(m[1].strip())
```